# Select2 search box

Tags: coffeescript, jquery-select2

I have a formatting issue with the following feature. As you'll see below, it mostly works, just the formatting of the search box is not what I want (I want to replicate the typeahead Twitter Bootstrap feature):

A user can enter a book title in a search box, get a selection of books to chose from (through ajax) in the dropdown under the searchbox, and select a book. Upon selection of a book in the dropdown, a form is filled up with the book information. Just like so:

[image]

My problem is that select2 automatically changes the format of the search input (adds css around the selected item in search box). See here:

[image]

**Question**

I know it's not exactly what Select2 is meant to be used for, but I'd like to have the search box value to be "rails", appearing exactly the way it was when I typed it (first screenshot). **How do I keep a regular input format?**

**Details:**

Here is the coffeescript code I have so far (it features asynchronous loading of the pictures, and formatting of the selection):

```
jQuery ->

  get_image = (unique_id, image_url) ->
    img = $("<img  />").load(->
      $(".#{unique_id} .typeahead_photo_wrapper").html(img)
    ).error(->
      $(".#{unique_id} .typeahead_photo_wrapper").html("No preview")
    ).addClass('typeahead_photo').attr({src: image_url}).fadeIn(500)


  format_item = (book) ->
    console.log book
    itm = ''
    itm += "<div class='typeahead_wrapper #{book.isbn}'>"
    itm += "<div class='typeahead_photo_wrapper'>"
    itm += "<div class='typeahead_photo'>...</div>"
    itm += "</div>"
    itm += "<div class='typeahead_labels'>"
    itm += "<div class='typeahead_primary'>#{book.title}</div>"
    itm += "<div class='typeahead_secondary'>#{book.author}</div>"
    itm += "</div>"
    itm += "</div>"

    get_image(book.isbn, book.image)
    itm


  update_with_item = (item) ->
    keywords = $("#learning_item_book_search").val()
    # console.log item

    $("#new-book #learning_item_unique_identifier").val(item.isbn)
    $("#new-book #learning_item_source").val(item.source)
    $("#new-book #learning_item_name").val(item.title)
    $("#new-book #learning_item_description").val(item.description)
    $("#new-book button").focus()
    item.title



  retrieve_books = (data) ->
    books = []
    $.each data, (i, item) ->
      books.push(
        id: item.id
        isbn: item.isbn
        title: item.title
        author: item.authors
        description: item.description
        image: item.volume_info.imageLinks.smallThumbnail
      )
    books


  $("#learning_item_book_search").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2
    tags: true
    ajax:
      url: "/raw_items/fetch_books"
      dataType: 'json'
      quietMillis: 200
      data: (term, page) ->
        query: term
      results: (data, page) ->
        return {results: retrieve_books(data)}
    maximumSelectionSize:1
    formatResult: format_item
    formatSelection: update_with_item
    formatInputTooShort: (term, minLength) ->
      "Searching book on Google books"
    dropdownCssClass: 'typeahead'
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

you can put select2 into multiselect mode - which will make it look like the regular text field you want. use maximumSelectionSize:1 option to limit selection to a single item. use 'change' event on the original html control to populate the form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As stated in the question and seen in the screenshots, populating the form already works. The only thing that does does not work is the styling of the search box: I want the "Book search field" to appear the same in screenshot 2 as it is in screenshot 1 (without the "tag" styling, and with the same keyword). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In `format_item` add a line

```
$("#learning_item_book_search").select2('val', '')
```

For multiselect

```
$("#learning_item_book_search").select2('val', [])
```

It will keep the search term instead of adding the selected item.